# Get comparison in PHP when equality sign is s string

Tags: php, comparison

I have two variables:

```
a = 5;
b = " > 6"
```

How could I get "true" or "false" for the comparison "5 > 6" using just `a` and `b`?

Comment: Is this homework? Smells like homework.

Comment: I have simplified my task. I need principle

Comment: The answer is evil (sp).

Comment: @JonStirling eval == evil

Comment: @AndrewL. Bah, you gave it away :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [eval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function. But I would highly discourage you from using it and so do the PHP documentation.

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the string and extract a number.

```
$var1 = 5;
$var2 = ' > 6';

preg_match("/[\d]+/", $var2, $matches);

$result = $var1 > intval($matches[0]);
var_dump($result);
```

You can go further and extract operator '>'. Now it's hardcoded.

Comment: Good job not using `eval()`

Comment: string may be different length with different number of digits and signs so using regular expression not always could help